# java: very large trees?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, large-data

The objective is to build very large trees.
By very large I mean hundreds of millions of nodes, fitting in a few gigabytes.

The issue is that common data structures have way too much overhead. I cannot afford to have "node" objects and children "maps". I need to directly encode it into memory in a very compact way.

Therefore, I was wondering if there existed some memory efficient implementation of trees having integers as key and values, without using objects internally, therefore needing (4 byte for key + 4 bytes for value + 4 bytes for children index + a few bytes for free hashing space = 15 bytes per entry on average) which would allow me to use an external mapping int<->keys and int<->values to search the tree.

Anyone?

PS: Using objects internally uses at least 5 times more space: 8 reference + 4 extra hash space + 16 object header + 8 key ref + 8 value ref + 8 parent ref + 8 children ref + (16 + x) for children map obj = nearly 76+x bytes per entry. (for instance, our default implementation needed around 100 bytes per entry)

Comment: how would it be more efficient to hold a reference to the object in the node?  Wouldn't that require an extra pointer's worth of memory for each held item, and an extra dereferencing cycle to get to the item?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I meant not using objects internally at all. Solely one (or a few) huge int[] arrays internally.

Comment: Does it *have* to be in Java? Would a (No)SQL database be a better option?

Comment: How many children per node? How can you get away with only four bytes per node for a children index unless the index is a pointer to the list of indexes of actual children?

Comment: @GregS: Exactly what you said, it is a pointer. 8 bytes may be necessary, or easier to handle, once the tree has more than 2^32 / 16 = 238 millions nodes.

Comment: @Rich: it does not have to be pure java. However, I have some doubts that SQL would satisfy our memory and performance problems ...more the opposite.

Comment: I think you're already in trouble since Java arrays are limited in size to Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31 - 1 values. You could of course implement a HugeArray class that internally manages arrays of arrays.

Comment: @GregS HugeCollections (see my answer) copes with Long.MAX_VALUE, I think.

Comment: @arnaud You should perhaps look into other systems such as MongoDB which can be *incredibly* quick. However that my not satisfy your memory requirements - it consumes a lot of memory and disk space.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually not a Java specific question but more of a general concept.

Try this: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/tree-as-array.html

The key would be to use arrays of primitives, in order to avoid object overhead.

Comment: that's for binary trees (and preferably balanced ones!). The solution for full trees is quite more complex.

Comment: @arnaud Well that was just a hint, since you didn't give that much information on the tree structure itself. You commented your question like this: `I meant not using objects internally at all. Solely one (or a few) huge int[] arrays internally.` which is essentially what I proposed.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your good intentions. It's just that I'm reluctant of making my own implementation due to the sheer complexity of the "full" solution ...it's really really complex ...every portion of the array would represent a mini-hashtable of the children, when it grows, it must be moved elsewhere, the space must then be recycled, the pointer of the parent must be updated, etc, etc... the balanced binary tree to array is a piece of cake compared to it.

Comment: @arnaud - then why did you say "The objective is to build very large trees"? Describe what you are actually trying to accomplish, and you might get better solutions. But I still wouldn't expect anything out of the box.

Comment: @parsifal: huh?! ...because the objective is "to build very large trees". (as a side note, the response here refers to balanced binary trees, which are by no means suited for normal trees. Implementing efficiently the latter one is extremely more complex than the mere bijection described in the article)

Comment: @arnaud - I'm clearly missing something in your question, because I don't consider a "tree" to be a particularly complex data structure, no matter how many children there are. Perhaps you're actually looking for a "trie"?

Comment: @parsifal: trie/tree? Is it really a big difference? They are both kindof the same to me ...actually "trie" and "prefix tree" are synonyms! So yeah, what I need is a tree/trie with ints as keys and ints as values, so that I can lookup/modify/delete the value associated to a sequence of keys. Therefore, it needs hash tables. Implementing a tree/trie is ok, putting everything in an array of bytes/ints and manage the different operations is more complex. As mentionned before, portions of this buffer would represent hashtables that have to be moved when they need to grow, space recycled, and so on

Comment: @arnaud - yes, it's a huge difference, and exactness is incredibly important in our profession. Every person that answered this question made an assumption based on your wording. If you had used "trie" or "prefix tree," they would not have done so.

Comment: @arnaud - responding to your actual question: you don't need to implement a trie using a hashtable. In fact, I would argue that hashtables are a very poor implementation, useful only for example code. A better implementation will depend on your data, but one way to do it is a simple sorted list of children.

Comment: @parsifal: there are many thousands of children per node. Hashing is the most efficient way to achieve quick lookups. I also simply didn't use "trie" because it is usually associated with strings, and not ints. However, just out of curiosity, what's your distinction between a "trie" having ints as key/values and a "tree" having ints as key/values? (for me it's the same)

Comment: @arnaud - for me it's how you traverse the structure, and consequently, the applications where it would be useful. And I would rarely if ever use the word "tree" without adornment: a tree is simply a parent-child structure (more formally, a directed graph in which each node has a single predecessor and zero or more successors, and there is a "root" node with no predecessor). A "binary tree" is only one type of a tree, "prefix tree," "B-tree," and "quadtree" are others, and there are dozens of tree structures that I have never had a need to work with.

Comment: But, to your specific needs: if you were to describe your data, and the way that you need to access that data, rather than stating your predefined solution and looking for an existing implementation, you'll get much more useful responses.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3105/discussion-between-arnaud-and-parsifal)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any specific tree implementation that does exactly that, but VTD-XML represents an XML tree (the DOM) internally using an array of tokens with pointers into a buffer. Perhaps you can get inspired by their solution?

Answer (score 1):

You may find that this library helps you achieve what you want - it is specifically designed for storing values as primitives and does some bytecode hackery behind the scenes to give the illusion of storing Objects. Use it when...

> ... you want to efficiently store large collections of data in memory. This library can dramatically reduce Full GC times and reduce memory consumption as well.

It doesn't have a specific Tree collection, but it might do the trick, depending on what you need.

http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find anything already implemented for you, but what you've described could be very easily implemented using an [IntBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html). You'd create a "wrapper" class that converts indexes into records in the buffer, and instantiate/discard those wrappers *as needed* (ie, as you're traversing a tree, you probably don't care about holding a reference to the parent).

There are a couple of concerns:

- Garbage collection of the wrapper instances: as long as they're short-lived, they never get out of Eden, so GC is almost free.
- Garbage collection of records within the buffer: if you have a write-once tree, this is no problem. Otherwise, you'll need to maintain a free list. Not difficult, but it takes some time.
- General mechanics of implementing a tree: this is already done for you with classes like `TreeMap`. But the algorithms are pretty simple, and available from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping a list of children, every node could have a reference to its parent. Thus serializing a node wouldn't need more than three integer values (parent, key, value).

A problem with this approach is tree traversal. Obtaining a definite list of all node children would require iterating through all nodes. If the tripplettes are sorted by their parent values traversal may be improved. Adding one more integer value, i.e. a pointer to the next key would allow keeping the nodes in a linked list easing the job of insertion and removal of nodes.

Comment: you need the ability to search the tree. For a given list of keys, you need to recover the value.